# can we revoke AWS SES Verified identities which was accepted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have accepted AWS SES Verified identities request, now I want to revoke or remove from this SES Verified identities, how I can do the same?

In request we have the AWS account id also , from that ID can we get the customer details so we can request them to delete the entry if its not possible to revoke from the my side.